# Additional Choice field for ordering

Tags: forms, symfony

I want to set the order for new entry. I need order to first position and order after one of the existing entries

I don't know how to manage this in Symfony 4.2

```php
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
   $builder
    ->add('nameDe')
    ->add('nameEn')
    ->add('descriptionDe')
    ->add('descriptionEn')
    ->add('rank', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => ProductType::class,
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->orderBy('p.rank', 'ASC');
        },
        'choice_label' => 'nameDe', 
    ])
    ->add('active')
    ->add('creatDate')
    ->add('updateDate', DateTimeType::class, array('data' => new \DateTime()));
}
```

I have this:

```
<select id="product_type_rank" name="product_type[rank]">
    <option value="1">Internetseiten</option>
    <option value="2">Printmedia</option>
</select>
```

I need something like this

```
<select id="product_type_rank" name="product_type[rank]">
    <option value="0">At the beginning</option>
    <option value="1">after Internetseiten</option>
    <option value="2">after Printmedia</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add custom text in your options, you can use the `choice_label` option like that :

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
   $builder
    ->add('nameDe')
    ->add('nameEn')
    ->add('descriptionDe')
    ->add('descriptionEn')
    ->add('rank', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => ProductType::class,
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
             ->orderBy('p.rank', 'ASC');
        },
        'choice_label' => function($productType) {
             return 'after ' . $productType->getNameDe();
        },
        'placeholder' => 'At the beginning',
    ])
    ->add('active')
    ->add('creatDate')
    ->add('updateDate', DateTimeType::class, array('data' => new \DateTime()));
}
```

With this one, you will have the expected result.

You can add a specific getter into your ProductType entity class and use it directly in the `choice_label`, like that :

**ProductType.php**

```php
class ProductType {
    ...

    getNameDeWithCustomText() {
        return 'after ' . $this->getNameDe();
    }
}
```

```php
'choice_label' => 'nameDeWithCustomText',
```

Comment: fantastic I tried a lot on my own, but this is exat what I am looking for, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a default option to your EntityType field, you can add a placeholder option like this

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
   $builder
    ->add('nameDe')
    ->add('nameEn')
    ->add('descriptionDe')
    ->add('descriptionEn')
    ->add('rank', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => ProductType::class,
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->orderBy('p.rank', 'ASC');
        },
        'choice_label' => 'nameDe',
        'placeholder' => 'At the beginning',
    ])
    ->add('active')
    ->add('creatDate')
    ->add('updateDate', DateTimeType::class, array('data' => new \DateTime()));
}
```

As I see, you are handling multiple languages in your form, if you want to internationalize your placeholder, just put the translation key directly in the value (you need to install the Symfony translation package : https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html)

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
   $builder
    ->add('nameDe')
    ->add('nameEn')
    ->add('descriptionDe')
    ->add('descriptionEn')
    ->add('rank', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => ProductType::class,
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->orderBy('p.rank', 'ASC');
        },
        'choice_label' => 'nameDe',
        'placeholder' => 'foo.bar.placeholder',
    ])
    ->add('active')
    ->add('creatDate')
    ->add('updateDate', DateTimeType::class, array('data' => new \DateTime()));
}
```

If the translation files don't exist, create them in `translations/` folder

```
# translations/messages.en.yaml
foo:
    bar:
        placeholder: At the beginning
```

```
# translations/messages.de.yaml
foo:
    bar:
        placeholder: Am Anfang
```